# How to overwrite JQuery plugin function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to overwrite a function which is from a JQuery plugin? I am trying to overwrite a function in csv2table plugin called mkTable() in my own javascript file. Is it possible? Here is the original definition:

```
$.fn.csv2table= function(url,setting) {
  function  mkTable(id,rowsAry){
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from outside the `csv2table` function scope since it is private to that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Looked at the source. There's nothing you can do.

The function is declared inside a closure and you don't have any access to it.

The real question is why are you parsing csv using a jQuery plugin?

It would be better to have the server handle the csv files and give the client JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Raynos. The reason why I want to send a single html file to have my task done...